# Better alternative to DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) for data refresh

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking for a better alternative to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5` to refresh my data.

My data is dynamic and changes based on user action, it's important that the data the user sees is always up to date.

I am using Firebase Realtime Database, I am wondering whether I can alter my service file to refetch data any time something changes. here is my service file:

```
class Service {
    static let shared = Service()
    let BASE_URL = "https://firebaseurl.com/jsondata.json"
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    func fetchClient(completion: @escaping ([Calls]) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            // handle error
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to fetch data with error: ", error)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let myDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                myDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
                let calls = try myDecoder.decode([Calls?].self, from: data).filter({
                    self.calendar.isDateInToday($0?.dateTime ?? Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -123456789.0)) 
                })
                
                completion(calls.filter{$0?.callmade != true}.compactMap{ $0 })
            } catch let error {
                print("Failed to create JSON with error: ", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Currently in my Main Controller I am using:

```
func fetchClient() {
    Service.shared.fetchClient { (client) in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.client = client
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.fetchClient()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Firebase have SDK with Observer that might update you each time there is a change instead of doing manually the request?

Comment: It does for Cloud Firestore, I couldn't find the solution for Realtime Database in the documentation though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Realtime Database to observer changes in data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events